# Adding and removing children ViewControllers to UIViewController when ToolBar Button is pressed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am implementing a UIViewController with ScrollView. In the centre of the view I have a ToolBar like that one in the picture:

I have four UIViewControllers to add, one for each button of the toolBar. I do not know if I should init all off them at the beginning and then with a NSArray of viewControllers and one  NSArray of booleans manage all of them with this methods:

**How could I manage this?? Change viewControllers at the bottom of the toolBar while any button is pressed**

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + content.view.frame.size.height );
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
    [scrollView addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          
}

- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
    [content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
}
```

I have never used childViewControllers actually and I really do not know  how to use them

[image: ToolBar View]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How could I manage this?? Change viewControllers at the bottom of the toolBar while any button is pressed?

Comment: I think there is no universal answer for that. You can create new view controller on tool bar action. You can also create them all any moment before (and store in array), or create them lazy, in getters. I don't know what exactly do you need.

Comment: But.. should I hide the rest when I show one? Or is it efficient if I put all over the rest, and just change position?

Comment: @RoxeeMan don't do that . ... roatation will cause several isues.

Comment: So is better if I use this method `hideContentController:` before I show the new one?

Comment: @Kunal Balani : why not using child view controllers? If you use them correctly, everything should work great (it was a problem before iOS 5 and container view controller possibilities)

Comment: I think I should use childViewControllers

Comment: @Roxee Man : I guess that depends on what you need ;) You may remove old view controller when adding new, and add some kind of transition between them. You may also stack them.

Comment: but, what is more efficient? Remove or stack them?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference in terms of efficiency.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41661/discussion-between-maciej-koziel-and-roxee-man)

Answer (score 0):

You want to essentially create your own TabBarcontroller. You should use child view controller otherwise auto rotation will not work as expected. You should use an array of ViewControllers (required to pass data) and delegates when your interact with your tabBar. Here is an excellent example which does the same.[MHTabBarController](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController).

Here is a sample interface for it:

```
@interface MHTabBarController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *selectedViewController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger selectedIndex;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id  delegate;

- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

Comment: But actually, I already have a TabBar at the bottom, but I also need the toolBar in the middle of the screen to change the viewcontrollers below

Comment: Don't we talk here about tool bar (I'm not sure ;) ), which may behave differently.

Comment: @RoxeeMan doesn't matter. Every UIViewController Container is a UIViewController.

Comment: Can I set this tabBar where ever I want? and if I do scroll at the view Could I move it?

Comment: No.. sorry, I need that the toolBar can move with the scrollview